# jQuery replace input placeholder using method replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `input` like this:

```
<input id="inputId" placeholder="Old Placeholder Here"/>
```

I want to replace `placeholder` using `.replaceWith()` method. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you are trying to change the value of the `placeholder` attribute, then you don't want to use `replaceWith()` as that is designed to replace an entire element with another.

Instead you should use `prop()`:

```
$('#inputId').prop('placeholder', 'New placeholder value...');
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

The [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method is to replace DOM elements, not attributes in elements. You should use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)or [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) methods for that.

```
$('input').attr('placeholder', 'new placeholder...');
```

jsFidle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pwdesfwq/

Answer (score 1):

To change attributes of an element use `$("<element>").attr("<attribute>", "<value>");`
In your case, it is

```
$("input").attr("placeholder", "Placeholder value");
```